# How to get an instance type from generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, ts-jest

I have the following classes:

```ts
export class ValidationFailedError extends Error {
  public errors: ValidationError[];

  constructor(errors: ValidationError[]) {
    super('Validation errors exist');

    this.errors = errors;
  }
}

export class ValidationError {}
export class DuplicateFileValidationError extends ValidationError {}
export class MultipleTransactionTypesValidationError extends ValidationError {}
export class FileIsPlacedInWrongFolderValidationError extends ValidationError {
  constructor(public fileName: string, public expectedFolder: string, public actualFolder: string) {
    super();
  }
}
export class InvalidTransactionsCountValidationError extends ValidationError {
  constructor(
    public transactionsCount: number,
    public minTransactionsCount: number,
    public maxTransactionsCount: number,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
```

And I have some tests (I'm using Jest) that check if function throws a `ValidationFailedError`, and then also checks, what is inside `ValidationFailedError.errors` array. For the tests I wrote the following helper function which checks that `ValidationFailedError` error contains only one error of provided `ValidationError`, and performs some custom asserts provided as a callback function which takes single argument - `ValidationError` with expected type as an argument:

```ts
function expectValidationFailedErrorContainsSingleError<T extends ValidationError>(
  validationFailedError: ValidationFailedError,
  errorCtor: T,
  customAssertAction?: (err: T) => void,
): void {
  const { errors } = validationFailedError;
  expect(Array.isArray(errors)).toBe(true);
  expect(errors.length).toEqual(1);

  const validationError = errors[0] as T;
  expect(validationError).toBeInstanceOf(errorCtor);

  customAssertAction(validationError);
}
```

The function above is compiled fine, however I have an issue with using this function in my tests. Please take a look at the example below, I took this piece of code from one of my tests:

```ts
expectValidationFailedErrorContainsSingleError(
  err,
  FileIsPlacedInWrongFolderValidationError,
  (validationError) => {
    expect(validationError.fileName).toEqual('test-file.json');
    expect(validationError.actualFolder).toEqual(actualFolder);
    expect(validationError.expectedFolder).toEqual(expectedFolder);
  },
);
```

Typescript does not recognize the type of `validationError` parameter, it raises the following 3 errors:

> Property 'fileName' does not exist on type 'typeof
> FileIsPlacedInWrongFolderValidationError'.ts(2339)
>
> Property 'actualFolder' does not exist on type 'typeof
> FileIsPlacedInWrongFolderValidationError'.ts(2339)
>
> Property 'expectedFolder' does not exist on type 'typeof
> FileIsPlacedInWrongFolderValidationError'.ts(2339)

When I hover on `validationError` parameter, I see that the type of this parameter is `typeof FileIsPlacedInWrongFolderValidationError` :

[image: Issue on hover]

I feel like the type of `validationError` is not an instance type, it's a class type.

**The Question**: Is it possible to fix this issue, so I can access the properties `fileName`, `actualFolder` and `expectedFolder` in the function?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6zaDw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz FYI, DustInComp has already written up the answer, I'm going to mark his answer as accepted, but you can write another answer and I'll vote up your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't plan on calling the `errorCtor` (since you can't know if or how many arguments it has here), this typing doesn't show any warnings on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-gEAMIQIxiGC0+GQ47Qs6FOlXWr+H6c4KhKBha1yvkWTne-XOPABoMwOxiIwgEyRaVp3X8uAgKVen45-2B4NFktlqAVjLphUgNi0es+qZ55uFuDF0vl2qWtNZHIp+29frUVBB31iRUkEKh8RSHYKKIB4PSH4AZS1siSAB53kcTjDtyyoAA+VMGD3R5y72T75R2B9fuQkk7LooD9ZMixIAB3OAwiaOC2CgUkYjEEg3UiVIOifOB3mApgjHITAAEFOEiGBCLXAB+OwIiUOx3jSdosLdCBBArFI7GYwQ2XjchEBArgUE6d84R3aRvySHoNxCMJCKUNhASaCpZK+QEaNKFIUiaUIACESDCRMSAXKSYDU6wmlkMkGk00J5AAR0NFgwgARntOMOTgYTmUOTpWmsNwAAYPDgDhsMk+ZNxMzzwSSayIF0glyG+PEAHlUFM0Dk1cvx8NCEBiLwUjyKmCimjCKKY2Ue0Bh4+BWg6McoKZcEAJ-cI3FqFDoLREhMRxP58SJElyUpE0HySPJ1HIAhBVkJoiDwcRsFlbAAHoSBgJgVvwAhJooZa1o2ra8AAfV2qpKA8FIbgi-8xMAg9xBgY88DPMkLyiV8SmA7retxAbiXEYa1SgMaomAsrzmiqIGKwq0uxqviZpIEUxVlfUHONctjJVEbIjgQSPMhiroDTcLpKRlHDK0iA7IciayBgaadjmhaxCqSSDDJkz0aNXGoFi2m+DyA7Nu2s6jM5+gIoiKXlQETH+epwXHNW9bRZO8XJKQNivCAA):

```
function expectValidationFailedErrorContainsSingleError<T extends ValidationError>(
  validationFailedError: ValidationFailedError,
  errorCtor: new (...args: never[]) => T, // Constructor type
  customAssertAction?: (err: T) => void,
): void {
  const { errors } = validationFailedError;
  expect(Array.isArray(errors)).toBe(true);
  expect(errors.length).toEqual(1);

  const validationError = errors[0] as T;
  expect(validationError).toBeInstanceOf(errorCtor);

  customAssertAction?.(validationError); // Note the optional chaining
}
```

```
const err = new ValidationFailedError([
  new FileIsPlacedInWrongFolderValidationError('test-file.json', '/etc/ts-test', '/etc/ts_test')
])
expectValidationFailedErrorContainsSingleError(
  err,
  FileIsPlacedInWrongFolderValidationError,
  (validationError) => {
    const { fileName, actualFolder, expectedFolder } = validationError
    expect(fileName).toEqual('test-file.json');
    expect(actualFolder).toEqual('/etc/ts-test');
    expect(expectedFolder).toEqual('/etc/ts_test');
  },
);
```